# React/Node js and mongodb, sending data, Collection is created but Schema data doesn't get sent?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs

So I have a React App that has a form which is suppose to send data typed into some text area boxes, to a node js backend and then into a mongodb instance. Most of this works, the React data sends to the Node server, and the Node server creates the collection in mongodb, However the Schema data doesn't appear to be getting collected. My console log from the React app shows the following,

```
{companyName: "linfox", curtainCodes: "#00000", sinageCodes: "#FFFFF", 
Notes: "test", Method: "typed stuff in"}

Method: "typed stuff in"Notes: 
"test"companyName: "linfox"curtainCodes: "#00000"sinageCodes: 
"#FFFFF"__proto__: Object

UserInput.js:36 Server added successfully
```

So the React App is working now the Node js code. (it is important to note that I am using [MLAB](https://mlab.com) for mongodb)

Server.js

```
//This code requires mongoose node module
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors')
const tfiPaintCodesRouter = require('./routes/tfiPaintCodesRouter');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const MONGO_URL = 'mongodb://link-to-mlab-instance';
mongoose.connect(MONGO_URL).then(
    () => {console.log('Database is connected') },
    err => { console.log('Can not connect to the database' +err)
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/saveInfo', tfiPaintCodesRouter);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Server listening on port " + port);
});
```

mongoDB SChema Code

```
// server/models/Article.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

  // Create schema
 const PaintInfoSchema =  new Schema({
        companyName: {
            type: String
        },
        curtainCodes: {
            type: String
        },
        sinageCodes: {
            type: String
        },
        Notes: {
            type: String
        },
        Method: {
            type: String
        },
    },{
      collection: 'tfiPaintCodes'
    });

module.exports = mongoose.model('PaintInfoSchema', PaintInfoSchema)
```

tfiPaintCodesRouter.js

```
// tfiPaintCodesRouter.js

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const tfiPaintCodesRouter = express.Router();

const PaintInfoSchema = require('../models/PaintInfoSchema.js');

tfiPaintCodesRouter.route('/add').post(function (req, res) {
  const tfipaintcode = new PaintInfoSchema(req.body);
  tfipaintcode.save()
    .then(tfipaintcode => {
        res.json('Server added successfully');
    })
    .catch(err => {
    res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
    });
});

tfiPaintCodesRouter.route('/').get(function (req, res) {
    PaintInfoSchema.find(function (err, tfipaintcodes){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      res.json(tfipaintcodes);
    }
  });
});

module.exports = tfiPaintCodesRouter;
```

Once the data is sent, I go to Mlab and can see the collection is created, as shown in this picture

[MongoDB collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9oG7.png)

However inside the collection my data response is as follows.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b7cbe075e4b2c20b02a789b"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

I'm not sure what I am missing! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In `const tfipaintcode = new PaintInfoSchema(req.body);`, what does `req.body` look like? If you insert a `console.log(req.body)` statement in your `tfiPaintCodesRouter.route` callback, what do you get?

Comment: Huh! I see the following
 
`[{"_id":"5b7cbbde2e62d81f689874c2","__v":0},{"_id":"5b7cbd6065b5c120488e4b71","__v":0},{"_id":"5b7cbe075e4b2c20b02a789b","__v":0},{"_id":"5b7cc0d9c44d9121a148074f","__v":0},{"_id":"5b7cc54b4b0261253e8311f8","__v":0},{"_id":"5b7cca094b0261253e8311f9","__v":0}]`

So that makes sense as to why i am seeing that in the instance, But why does it show like this?

Comment: Not sure, but an incorrectly formatted object being eventually sent to `tfipaintcode.save()` would explain why nothing is being saved. I advise you do some careful console.logging, and/or use request formatter like Postman, to track what's going on in your routes on both the client- and server-side. Sorry to send you back to the drawing board, but I advise you do that before continuing this line of questioning.

Comment: Yeah i will have a play, Thanks for the response, You at least got me a bit further along :)

Comment: I figured it out,If anyone runs into this same issue, It was actually in my React App I had some code:
`
 onSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // get our form data out of state
        const tfiInfo = { 
        companyName: this.state.name,
        curtainCodes: this.state.name,
        sinageCodes: this.state.name,
        Notes: this.state.name,
        Method: this.state.name
      } 
`
Where I had .name it meeded to be the name of the state itself, so:

`companyName = this.state.companyName` 

That was it! doh, easy mistake.